# Pandas iterrows not working within function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm creating a small scale scheduling script, and having some issues with iterrows. These are very small df's so time is minimal (6 rows and maybe 7/8 columns), although i'm guessing these loops are not the most efficient - I am pretty new to this!

Here's what I have already

```
data = {'Staff 1': ['9-5', '9-5', '9-5', '9-5', '9-5'], 
         'Staff 2': ['9-5', '9-5', '9-5', '9-5', '9-5'],
            'Staff 3': [ '9-5', '9-5', '9-5', '9-5', '9-5']}
dataframe_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index',
                        columns=['9/2/19', '9/3/19', '9/4/19', '9/5/19', '9/6/19'])

data2 = {'Name': ['Staff 1','Staff 2','Staff 3'], 'Site': ['2','2','2'], 'OT':['yes','yes','no'],
         'Days off':['','9/4/19','9/4/19'], '':['','','9/5/19']}

dataframe_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)


def annual_leave(staff, df):
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        days_off = []
        if df.loc[index,'Name'] == '{}'.format(staff):
            for cell in row:                
                days_off.append(cell)
            del days_off[0:3]
        else:
            pass

        return days_off

for index, row in dataframe_1.iterrows():
    print(annual_leave(index, dataframe_2))
```

I added in a few 'print(index)' in places to see if I could work out where it was going wrong.

I found that the bottom iterrows loop is running through each row. However, the itterrows loop in the function is only looking at the first row and I don't understand why.

I am trying to go through each staff name (the index) in dataframe_1, and checking that staff name against a column name in dataframe_2. I then want to get rid of the first 3 columns of that particular row in dataframe_2 (hence the list and del days_off[0:3]).

However in this example it is running the bottom for iterrows loop (outside of the function) for 'Staff 1', 'Staff 2', and 'Staff 3'. But the itterrows loop inside the function is only checking against the 'Staff 1' name.

This means it only works for 'Staff 1', but when the function is called for 'Staff 2', it is only checking for 'Staff 2' in the first row of dataframe_2 - and not finding it because its in the second row.

Does this make any sense?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add some sample input and expected output—it's small anyway. `df.to_clipboard(False)` is made for this. And I know pandas is hard, I'd rather learn it once by learning it right.

Comment: Thank, I have added some sample data and a bit more of an explanation. I looked at the to_clipboard and im not sure if thats right for this -  i may just not understand it tho.

Comment: `to_clipboard` mean to copy it the clipboard. You then paste it to your question. Save quite a bit of typing. Also, you missed one thing: what is your expected output?

Comment: ahh ok, thanks - that would have helped. I am expecting the function to go through each of the rows in dataframe 2 (with iterrows), but it only seems to be going through the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling the function ? Executing the above code which you have given will just create a function and you need to call it by passing proper arguments to see the output. I couldn't find any other mistakes in the code. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi, i think i'm calling the function within the for loop at the bottom. I just have it in print() to see what was happening

Answer (score 0):

It is because your return is inside the iterrows for loop. return needs to be unindented in order to be outside the for loop.